# c programming free in a own function

Tags: c, struct, free

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Mage{
    int power;
    char* name;
}typedef Mage;

void print(Mage* mage){
    printf("Mage: %s, Power: %i", mage->name, mage->power);
}

Mage create(char name[],int power){
    Mage* mage = malloc(sizeof(Mage));
    mage->power = power;
    mage->name = name;
    printf("New Mage!\n");
    return *mage;
}

void delete(Mage* mage){
    free(mage); // -> this is not working
    // how can I use free in an own function
    // I don't want to write free in main
}

int main() {

    Mage gandalf = create("Gandalf",50);
    print(&gandalf);
    delete(&gandalf);

    printf("\n\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

how can I use free in an own function, 
I don't want to write free in main, 
this source code contains a free, 
this program crashes

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Hint: when your program crashes on calling `free` it's a sign of poor memory management somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem with your approach here is that you are in fact returning a Mage struct in your `create` function, not a pointer to a Mage struct.

That means that Mage gandalf in `main` is not actually at the same address as the Mage allocated by malloc in `create`.

If instead you would return Mage (meaning the address) in `create`, and then would declare gandalf as a Mage* (a pointer to a Mage struct), you could then use gandalf directly (without &) in your `print` and `delete` function and it would refer to the same Mage you allocated in `create` originally.

If it's not clear, I'm confident you should reread chapters pointers if you've been reading a C tutorial.

Hope this helped, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Mage{
    int power;
    char* name;
}typedef Mage;

void print(Mage* mage){
    printf("Mage: %s, Power: %i", mage->name, mage->power);
}

Mage* create(char name[],int power){
    Mage* mage = malloc(sizeof(Mage));
    mage->power = power;
    mage->name = name;
    printf("New Mage!\n");
    return mage;
}

void delete(Mage* mage){
    free(mage);
}

int main() {

    Mage *gandalf = create("Gandalf",50);
    print(gandalf);
    delete(gandalf);

    printf("\n\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```